# Scala - recursive compare function

Tags: scala, recursion

I'm working on a function to recursively run through a list of Ints and return a Boolean stating whether each item in the list is the same number. I've taken a stab at it below but it's not passing the tests I'm running. Here's what I've got, any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

```
def equalList (xs : List[Int]) : Boolean = {
def equalAux (xs:List[Int], value:Int) : Boolean = {
    xs match {
        case Nil => true
        case x :: xs if (x == value) => equalAux(xs, x)
        case x :: xs if (x != value) => false  
          }
}
  equalAux(xs, x)
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a case that this is failing on?

Comment: Now I'm actually getting a compiling error when I call my aux function, stating "not found: value x". I try changing it to "xs.head" but that will not work with an empty list. I believe thats the case that was failing before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said in your comment, you just need to make sure the list is not empty so you can give an initial value to your recursive function:

```
def equalList(xs: List[Int]): Boolean = {

  def equalAux (xs: List[Int], value: Int): Boolean = {
    xs match {
      case Nil => true
      case x :: xs if x == value => equalAux(xs, x)
      case x :: _ if x != value => false
    }
  }

  // Check to make sure the list has at least one item initially
  xs match {
    case Nil => true
    case head :: tail => equalAux(tail, head)
  }
}

println(equalList(List.empty))           // true
println(equalList(List(1)))              // true
println(equalList(List(1, 1, 1, 1)))     // true
println(equalList(List(1, 1, 1, 1, 2)))  // false
println(equalList(List(1, 2, 1)))        // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a recursive function? If not, I would use Set as a trick:

```
myList.toSet.size <= 1 // because empty list returns true. Else make it == 1
```

If you do need recursion, then @Tyler answer is the answer I would also give.